# Show comments for each sheet of a workbook in a MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display all comment text for each worksheet in the `Activeworkbook` in a `MsgBox` (for each comment).

My code isn't throwing an error, so I know I am close.

```
Sub ShowAllWorkbookcomments()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim cmt As String
Dim commentcount As Integer

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
commentcount = rng.Count
'cmt = ws.rng.Comment.Text

Dim varComment As String
Dim c As Comment

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case commentcount
        Case 0
            MsgBox "No Comment", vbExclamation
            Resume Next
        Case Is > 0            
            For Each cell In rng
                varComment = c.Text
                MsgBox varComment, vbInformation
            Next cell
    End Select

    Set rng = Nothing            
Next ws    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, just needed to get the `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)` inside the `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` loop.

Also, added another way to trap the possibility of a worksheet having no comments, and removed the unnecessary `Select Case`.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowAllWorkbookcomments()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cmt As String
Dim varComment As String

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<-- current worksheet has comments
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            'varComment = cell.Comment.text
            varComment = "worksheet " & ws.Name & " comment " & cell.Comment.text ' <-- added the worksheet name as reference 
            MsgBox varComment, vbInformation
        Next cell
    Else '<-- current worksheet has No comments >> rng is Nothing
        'MsgBox "No Comment", vbExclamation
        MsgBox "worksheet " & ws.Name & " has No Comments", vbExclamation ' <-- added the worksheet name as reference 
    End If
    Set rng = Nothing
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS it worked! Do you mind briefly explaning why cell would be a Range instead of a variant or object? , and also what the Set rng = nothing at the end of the loop is doing? (Assuming that it clears the rng, for the next WS, which then sets based on the new sheet) .Finally, when you say for each cell in rng.cells, do you need the .cells part there (since we have already declared the range for the cells)?

Comment: @MikeMirabelli in order to loop through a `Range` you use a `Range` that servs as a single `Cell`, that way you can access the `Range.Value` or in your case `cell.Comment.text`. `Set rng = Nothing` like you mentioned, clear before `Next ws`. Not necessary to add the `.Cells`, it's enough to use `For Each cell In rng`. You can feel free to mark as "Answer" :)

Comment: The above logic will not work if you have comments on merged cells. Please refer to the following answer to overcome that problem. [Looping through comments on merged cells] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643865/looping-through-comments-on-an-excel-workbook-in-vba-with-merged-cells)

Comment: @DeepakV read the PO carefully, he didn't ask for Merged cells

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, I got that the PO did not ask for Merged Cells. However, when you are looping through the comments in a sheet and if the comment is on a merged cell, the above code will return the comment text 'n' number of times, wherein 'n' is the number of cells merged. I faced this issue recently, so I shared that knowledge here.

Comment: @ShaiRado My comment was not to take away any credit from your answer :). Your answer is correct. In fact, I had also used the same logic for my implementation and got weird results when I encountered merged cells, hence the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments above, the above logic will cause the MsgBox to be shown for each of the cells in a merged range. The following logic will loop-through the comments in a given sheet, it will work for merged rows/cols scenario as well.

```vb
For Each CommentedSheets In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If CommentedSheets.Comments.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "worksheet " & CommentedSheets.Name & " has No Comments", vbExclamation
    Else
        For Each Individual_Comment In CommentedSheets.Comments
            varComment = "worksheet " & CommentedSheets.Name & " comment " & Individual_Comment.text
            MsgBox varComment, vbInformation
```